# How can I get DetailedSpeechRecognitionResult from Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently evaluating Azure CognitiveServices Speech. In the API documentation I see that there is a DetailedSpeechRecognitionResult class but I can't find a way to get it.
I create SpeechRecognizer like this:

```
var recognizer = factory.CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput(filePath, "en-US", SpeechOutputFormat.Detailed)
```

but I can't find in the documentation a function to return DetailedSpeechRecognitionResult from the SpeechRecognizer.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. To get the detailed result you should use

```
SpeechRecognitionResultExtensions.Best(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok you can use this follow. First if you use StartContinuousRecognitionAsync() process (when you try to recognized more of 15 second of speech) then you need to create an event inside of CreateSpeechRecognizerWithFileInput function:

```
    private async Task RecognitionStart(SpeechRecognizer recognition, TaskCompletionSource<int> breakProcess)
{
recognition.Recognized += RecognizedEventHandler;
}
```

and after, in the event Handler, you can to show the answer detailed of Azure:

```
 private void RecognizedEventHandler(object sender,SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result.Text))
        {
            List<DetailedSpeechRecognitionResult> theBestResult = e.Result.Best().ToList();
            resultingText = $"{string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, e.Result.Text)} [Confidence:{theBestResult[0].Confidence}] \n";                
        }
    }
```